# Wind River Linux, Failed Dependency Error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rpm, rpmbuild, wind-river-workbench

I am working on Wind River Linux. Failed Dependency Error. Can anyone please tell me what I have to do ? I have been trying from past one day

```
root@AC-04:/home/mysql# rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm
warning: MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5072e1f5
error: Failed dependencies:
        /sbin/chkconfig is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
        /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
        /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/debug is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use -Uvh instead of -ivh when installing: -Uvh is almost (kernel is the one exception) the right way to install/upgrade rpm packages.

The final solution will be to find the packages that provide those dependencies using (if all else fails)

```
rpm -qP /sbin/chkconfig *.rpm
```

on the WRL packages, and make sure those packages are installed.

Those are all file/directpory dependencies. Try (e.g.)

```
rpm -qf --whatprovides /sbin/chkconfig
```

to see if there is a package that provides the file.

(Note: what follows "works" for RPM5 on WRL, not RPM on Fedora/RHEL)

You can stub out dependencies by doing (e.g.)

```
mkdir -p /etc/rpm/sysinfo

echo "/sbin/chkconfig" >> /etc/rpm/sysinfo/Requirename
```

Masking the dependencies will permit installation (so will --nodeps) and might help get you further along in debugging your packaging.